# Expected dynamic type `double', but had type `null' (Constructing arguments for Timing.createTimer at index 1)

Tags: android, react-native

I have been getting this error `` Expected dynamic type `double', but had type `null' (Constructing arguments for Timing.createTimer at index 1) `` when I run react-native android. When I try locating Timing.createTimer I found it that it's being used in 3 places inside `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js`:

1

```
setTimeout: function(
func: Function,
duration: number,
...args?: any
): number {
    if (__DEV__ && IS_ANDROID && duration > MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS) {
      console.warn(
        ANDROID_LONG_TIMER_MESSAGE +
          '\n' +
          '(Saw setTimeout with duration ' +
          duration +
          'ms)',
      );
    }
    const id = _allocateCallback(
      () => func.apply(undefined, args),
      'setTimeout',
    );
    Timing.createTimer(id, duration || 0, Date.now(), /* recurring */ false);
    return id;
  }
```

2

```
setInterval: function(
func: Function,
duration: number,
...args?: any


): number {
    if (__DEV__ && IS_ANDROID && duration > MAX_TIMER_DURATION_MS) {
      console.warn(
        ANDROID_LONG_TIMER_MESSAGE +
          '\n' +
          '(Saw setInterval with duration ' +
          duration +
          'ms)',
      );
    }
    const id = _allocateCallback(
      () => func.apply(undefined, args),
      'setInterval',
    );
    Timing.createTimer(id, duration || 0, Date.now(), /* recurring */ true);
    return id;
  }
```

3

```
  requestAnimationFrame: function(func: Function) {
    const id = _allocateCallback(func, 'requestAnimationFrame');
    Timing.createTimer(id, 1, Date.now(), /* recurring */ false);
    return id;
  }
```

invoke method is define inside `JavaMethodWrapper.java` 368 line

```
   @Override
   public void invoke(JSInstance jsInstance, ReadableNativeArray parameters) {
    ....
        try {
            for (; i < mArgumentExtractors.length; i++) {
              mArguments[i] = mArgumentExtractors[i].extractArgument(
                jsInstance, parameters, jsArgumentsConsumed);
              jsArgumentsConsumed += mArgumentExtractors[i].getJSArgumentsNeeded();
            }
          } catch (UnexpectedNativeTypeException e) {
            throw new NativeArgumentsParseException(
              e.getMessage() + " (constructing arguments for " + traceName + " at argument index " +
                getAffectedRange(jsArgumentsConsumed, mArgumentExtractors[i].getJSArgumentsNeeded()) +
                ")",
              e);
          }
....
}
```

And it's being called from `JavaModuleWrapper.java` 162

```
    @DoNotStrip
  public void invoke(int methodId, ReadableNativeArray parameters) {
    if (mMethods == null || methodId >= mMethods.size()) {
      return;
    }

    mMethods.get(methodId).invoke(mJSInstance, parameters);
  }
```

Things I tried:

1. Tried guarding against a null id before Timing.createTimer is being called by doing `if (id == null || id = '') { return null }`
2. Tried printing the id that was being set before Timing.createTimer, but it caused the app to stop responding since it's triggering almost every second

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

PS: I read about every post there is related to this problem couldn't find a solution that applies

Comment: I'm not much familiar with JS, just trying to help, It's saying index 1, so is it about 2nd parameter? can duration(number) ever be null?

Comment: Hi @Man, it could be null when you call `clearInterval()` but that's why there is a default value so if duration is null it would default to 0. `Timing.createTimer(id, duration || 0, Date.now(), /* recurring */ true);`

Comment: "Timing.createTimer(id, 1, Date.now(), /* recurring */ false);" --> if duration needs to be a double, is the value "1" here incorrect then?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the solutions here (there are multiple different that has worked for different users):
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2387

> Figured out what my issue was, but it's odd as hell.. I only had a right chevron icon, so I applied a 180 degree rotate transform on it for my back button.. When I pressed on goBack, I had this same error: TypeError:expected dynamic type 'double',but had type 'string'.. If I remove the rotation transform everything works lol... Pretty odd..